# TypeError: super(type, obj) when using exec()

Tags: python, kivy

Below is the whole (test) app written with Kivy.
This is something like app preview application:
user enters a text of kv markup (see variable self.kv) and a text of classes (see variable self.text). Then he clicks the "preview" button and sees the result on the right side of the application.
Loading kv is implemented using kivy Builder.load_string(). Class loading is implemented using exec(, globals()).

The main problem is that for some reason I get the following error when I click on the preview button for the third time (the first 2 clicks work without errors):

`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

The error can be because of exec(), (without exec I don’t get this error).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        CodeEd
            id: code_editor

        Button:
            text: 'Preview'
            on_release: app.preview()

    Preview:
        id: preview_area

<CodeEd@TextInput>
    text: app.text

<Preview@RelativeLayout>
'''

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self._kv_filename = 'KvEditor_internal.' + str(self.uid)

        self.text = '''
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print (333)
        super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


'''
        self.kv = 'MyButton'

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)


    def preview(self):
        preview_area = self.root.ids.preview_area

        #if 'MyButton' in globals():
        #    del globals()['MyButton']

        #print ('===================')
        #print ([i for i in dict(globals())])

        try:
            exec(self.text, globals())
        except:
            print ('some error when exec class ')

        Builder.unload_file(self._kv_filename)

        try:

            preview_area.add_widget(Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename))

        except Exception as e:
            print (e.message if getattr(e, r"message", None) else str(e))


MyApp().run()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show the stacktrace? right now you have `except:`s which would block that from showing up as far as I can tell?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wKssVvWC, same without try/ecxept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question - Preview area is RelativeLayout

> It seems to work, but could you edit or add an example, please? I do
>   not need the number of buttons in the preview area increased. I just
>   want every time after pressing "Preview", in the preview area I have
>   content that just reflects the current text of self.kv and self.text.

## Example

The following example has most of the enhancements applied and the `Preview` area is a `RelativeLayout`.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.factory import Factory

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        CodeEd
            id: code_editor

        Button:
            text: 'Preview'
            on_release: app.preview()

    Preview:
        id: preview_area

<CodeEd@TextInput>
    text: app.text

<Preview@RelativeLayout>
'''


class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty('')
    previous_text = StringProperty('')

    def build(self):
        self._kv_filename = 'KvEditor_internal.' + str(self.uid)

        self.text = '''
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print (333)
        return super(Button, self).on_touch_down(touch)
'''

        self.previous_text = self.text
        self.kv = 'MyButton'

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def preview(self):
        preview_area = self.root.ids.preview_area
        self.text = self.root.ids.code_editor.text

        try:
            # Class loading is implemented using exec(, globals())
            exec(self.text, globals())
        except:
            print('some error when exec class ')

        Builder.unload_file(self._kv_filename)

        try:
            # check for code changes
            if self.text != self.previous_text:
                Factory.unregister(self.kv)
                Factory.register(self.kv, cls=globals()[self.kv])
                total_children = len(preview_area.children)
                preview_area.clear_widgets()
                for child in range(total_children):
                    preview_area.add_widget(Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename))
                self.previous_text = self.text

            preview_area.add_widget(Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message if getattr(e, r"message", None) else str(e))


MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result 1 - No changes to MyButton class]
[image: Result 2 - Changes to MyButton class]

## Question 1 - TypeError

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of
>   type

### Solution - TypeError

There are two solutions to the `TypeError`.

**Method 1**

Replace `super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)` with `return False`

**Method 2**

Replace `super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)` with `return super(Button, self).on_touch_down(touch)`

## Question 2 - Support code changes to MyButton class

> What if MyButton class exists, but I want to make changes to this
>   class, for example change some of its methods, and so on?

## Solution - Support code changes to MyButton class

In order to support code changes to `MyButton` class, the following enhancements are required:

- Add import statement for Kivy Properties, `from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty`
- Add import statement for Kivy Factory object, `from kivy.factory import Factory`
- Add a new class attribute, `previous_text` of type, `StringProperty` to keep track of code changes.
- Initialize `self.previous_text`
- Update `self.text` when method `preview()` is invoked.
- Check for code changes
- Unregister previous `class MyButton` using Kivy `Factory`
- Register new `class MyButton` using Kivy `Factory`
- Save the total number of `MyButton` added
- Remove previously added `MyButton` using `clear_widgets()`. If previously added `MyButton`s are not removed, it will not have the functionality of the new features/code changes.
- Use `for` loop to re-add previously added `MyButton` with the new functionality / features.
- Assign new code changes, `self.text` to `self.previous_text`

#### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.logger import Logger
...
class MyApp(App):
    i = NumericProperty(0)
    text = StringProperty('')
    previous_text = StringProperty('')

    def build(self):
        ...
        self.text = '''
        ...
            return True    # consumed on_touch_down & don't propagate
        # return False
        return super(Button, self).on_touch_down(touch)
'''

        self.previous_text = self.text
        ...

    def preview(self):
        preview_area = self.root.ids.preview_area

        self.text = self.root.ids.code_editor.text
        ...
        try:
            # check for code changes
            if self.text != self.previous_text:
                Factory.unregister(self.kv)
                Factory.register(self.kv, cls=globals()[self.kv])
                total_children = len(preview_area.children)
                preview_area.clear_widgets()
                for child in range(total_children):
                    btn = Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename)
                    btn.text = str(child + 1)
                    preview_area.add_widget(btn)
                self.previous_text = self.text
```

## Example

The following example illustrates a code editor supporting code changes to `MyButton` class, and `MyButton` widgets are added into a `GridLayout`.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.factory import Factory

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        CodeEd
            id: code_editor

        Button:
            text: 'Preview'
            on_release: app.preview()

    Preview:
        id: preview_area

<CodeEd@TextInput>:
    text: app.text

<Preview@GridLayout>:
    cols: 3
'''


class MyApp(App):
    i = NumericProperty(0)
    text = StringProperty('')
    previous_text = StringProperty('')

    def build(self):
        self._kv_filename = 'KvEditor_internal.' + str(self.uid)

        self.text = '''
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"touch.pos={touch.pos}")
            print(f"Button.text={self.text}")
            return True    # consumed on_touch_down & don't propagate
        # return False
        return super(Button, self).on_touch_down(touch)
'''

        self.previous_text = self.text
        self.kv = 'MyButton'

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def preview(self):
        preview_area = self.root.ids.preview_area

        self.text = self.root.ids.code_editor.text

        try:
            # Class loading is implemented using exec(, globals())
            exec(self.text, globals())
        except Exception as msg:
            print('\nException: some error when exec class ')
            Logger.error("KivyApp: Exception: some error when exec class")
            print(msg)
            quit()

        Builder.unload_file(self._kv_filename)

        try:
            # check for code changes
            if self.text != self.previous_text:
                Factory.unregister(self.kv)
                Factory.register(self.kv, cls=globals()['MyButton'])
                total_children = len(preview_area.children)
                preview_area.clear_widgets()
                for child in range(total_children):
                    btn = Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename)
                    btn.text = str(child + 1)
                    preview_area.add_widget(btn)
                self.previous_text = self.text

            self.i += 1
            btn = Builder.load_string(self.kv, filename=self._kv_filename)
            btn.text = str(self.i)
            preview_area.add_widget(btn)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message if getattr(e, r"message", None) else str(e))


MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result1 - No code changed]
[image: Result2 - Code changed]

Comment: What if MyButton class exists, but I want to make changes to this class, for example change some of its methods, and so on? I think it is necessary to delete previously created MyButton each time, I tried using del (it remains in the code), but for some reason it does not work

Comment: @me2beats: Please check updated post to support code changes.

Comment: It seems to work, but could you edit or add an example, please? I do not need the number of buttons in the preview area increased. I just want every time after pressing "Preview", in the preview area I have content that just reflects the current text of self.kv and self.text.

Comment: although the current version is also useful

Comment: Please refer to updated post with example of `Preview` area of type `RelativeLayout`.